# Tokenize date-format string

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to build a function that can convert a date format string like

```
%d/%m/%Y %H:%n
```

(variables are always % and one character) into an token array:

```
["%d", "/", "%m", "/", "%Y", " ", "%H", ":", "%n"]
```

But I fail to see how I can do that in an easy way.

Is there any technique / pattern / similar code to realize that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let pattern = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%n";
let tokens = pattern.match(/%.|[^%]+/g);

console.log(tokens);
```

The regex picks either % plus one character (`%.`) or anything else until the reaches next % character (`[^%]+`). The `g` modifier keeps doing that until the end of the string.